# Python regex - greedy quantifier not working in all cases

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

Further to this question, I am attempting to isolate/return the first int or float before an `x` (multiplication sign).

Here are my test strings:

```
2 x 3 kg PPG etc #returns 2
bob 2 x 3 kg PPG etc #returns 2
1.5x1.5kgPPGetcFred #returns 1.5
BobFred1.5x1.5kgPPGetcFred #returns 1.5
1.5 x 2.3 kg PPG Fred Bob #returns 5 (should return 1.5)
bob Fred 1.5 x 2.3 kg PPG Fred Bob #returns 5 (should return 1.5)
```

Here is my regex:

```
.*?(\d+)(\.?)(\s*)(\d?)(x)(.*)
```

It works for all of the above test strings *except* the last two. Vos iss up??

[RegEx101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o3Vwus/1)

**Python code example:**

```
import re

regex = r'.*?(\d+)(\.?)(\s*)(\d?)(x)(.*)'
regout = r'\1\2\4'
test_str = "1.5 x 2.3 kg PPG Fred Bob"

tmp = re.sub(regex, regout, test_str)
print(tmp)
```

Comment: I could make it doing: `(\d*\.?\d+)\s*(?=x)`

Comment: Hi guijob - thanks. I just tried your regex with the [RegEx101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/o3Vwus/1/) that I posted above, and it doesn't seem to work. Would you mind editing/forking the demo and show how it should modified to work?

Comment: @guijob - Never mind, [I got it](https://regex101.com/r/o3Vwus/2): `.*?(\d*\.?\d+)\s*(?=x).*`  ***Please turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it as correct.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For matching numbers with a dot before a `x` you can use this regex: `(\d*\.?\d+)\s*(?=x)`.

- `(\d*\.?\d+)` creates a group with digits, either between dots like: 1, 10, 1.3, 1.5, 22.10, etc.
- `\s*` matches whitespaces zero to unlimited times (between number and x can have whitespaces)
- `(?=x)` makes sure everything in right before a `x`

If you'd like to use `.sub()` then you must match entire string and this can be done using `.*?(\d*\.?\d+)\s*(?=x).*`, like you mentioned in comments.

---

EDIT: OP asks for matching number right after `x`.

For this, it's almost the inverse terms of previous regex, but instead of using positive lookahead `(?=)`, you make use of positive lookbehind `(?<=)`. So, when you use `(?<=x)` you want to make sure everything is after a `x`.

With this, to match you could use `(?<=x)\s*?(\d*\.?\d+)` and for .sub() you could `.*?(?<=x)\s*?(\d*\.?\d+).*`

Link for regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/EfzQOj/1).

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer and assistance - one more quick question: how can I next capture just the numbers *after* the `x` ?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you might want to design an expression maybe similar to:

```
(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)\s*x\s*(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)
```

assuming that .05 would be a valid number.

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)\s*x\s*(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)"
test_str = """
2 x 3 kg PPG etc
bob 2 x 3 kg PPG etc
1.5x1.5kgPPGetcFred
BobFred1.5x1.5kgPPGetcFred
1.5 x 2.3 kg PPG Fred Bob
bob Fred 1.5 x 2.3 kg PPG Fred Bob
bob Fred .005 x 2.3 kg PPG Fred Bob
"""

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
[('2', '3'), ('2', '3'), ('1.5', '1.5'), ('1.5', '1.5'), ('1.5', '2.3'), ('1.5', '2.3'), ('.005', '2.3')]
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/n83zZL/1), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/n83zZL/1debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Comment: Hi again Emma - and Thanks very much for the answer and assistance. One more quick question: how can I next capture just the numbers *after* the `x` ?